# Why SQL Server sql query returns empty list?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please note I am aware that it must be something simple and probably obvious - I just cannot see it ... As stated, do you know why this sql query would return empty list when executed on SQL Server (via SQL Server Management Studio), provided **THERE IS DATA IN APPROPRIATE TABLES AND ALL THE PARAMETERS OF THE QUERY ARE SET CORRECTLY?**

This question is linked to my other question ([Does anyone know why JPQL query on a view with SQL Server does not work? 'GetResultList' always returns empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379998/does-anyone-know-why-jpql-query-on-a-view-with-sql-server-does-not-work-getres)) but at this stage it actually turns into a separate topic, so therefore I have placed it here. Here is the query:

```
SELECT t1.Id,
         t2.IdTransiti,
         t1.CodiceCaricoPericoloso,
         t1.Confidenza,
         t1.Istante,
         t1.IstanteRicezione,
         t2.SQLServer_latitude,
         t2.SQLServer_longitude,
         t1.Partizione,
         t1.Targa,
         t1.TargaSecondaria,
         t1.UtmcInstanceId,
         t1.VelocitaStimata,
         t1.IdColore,
         t1.IdCorsia,
         t1.IdMarca,
         t1.IdModello,
         t1.IdNazionalita,
         t1.IdSerie,
         t1.IdTipologiaVeicolo
    FROM dbo.TransitiView t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Serie t0
       ON (t0.Id = t1.IdSerie)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Colori t3
       ON (t3.Id = t1.IdColore)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Modelli t4
       ON (t4.Id = t1.IdModello)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Marche t5
       ON (t5.Id = t1.IdMarca),
    TransitiPunti t2,
    Corsie t6
   WHERE ( ( ( ( ( (t6.Attiva = 1)
                  AND (t1.Istante BETWEEN '2015-09-03 00:16:50.693'
                                      AND '2015-09-03 23:16:50.693'))
                AND ( (t1.Partizione = 0) OR (t1.Partizione = 6)))
              AND (t1.IdCorsia = 1))
            AND (t2.IdTransiti = t1.Id))
          AND (t6.Id = t1.IdCorsia))
ORDER BY t1.Istante DESC
```

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to russ answer I now know what is going on - SQL Server does not like empty records in inner joins - ODD!! **Please, does any one of you know how and if it is possible to make SQL Server "LIKE" inner joins where entries may be missing in corresponding columns in joined tables?** Or... At least how to make it work for this particular query?

I thought to make it: ...ON (t2.IdTransiti = t1.Id or t2.IdTransiti is null) but that is NOT good enough for SQL Server. it didn't help :(.

BONUS QUESTION: Any idea why it is ok for MySQL but not for SQL Server when tables joined via inner joins may be empty? Why should this be NOT ok in a first place?

---

**EDIT:**

**ANSWER TO THE PROBLEM:**
Thanks to russ - I basically got it - it is just my confusion and nothing more. Please read comments under the accepted answer. Everything stems from the fact I forgot, didn't know that `@SecondaryTable` annotation in JPA translates to inner join and then double confusion - by my disregard **THAT OBVIOUSLY INNER JOIN EXPECTS VALUES IN BOTH TABLES !!!**

Thanks to everyone for their effort and I guess I have to think little bit more before stating things next time around :).

Comment: Do not mix explicit join syntax and old implicit join!!! Too easy to make mistakes - use new, explicit join syntax only!!!

Comment: Move t2 etc conditions from WHERE to ON, to get true LEFT JOIN. (As it is now, it executes as regular inner join...)

Comment: @jarhl Thank you Jahrl! But what is interesting, this query is actually autogenerated by Microsoft sqljdbc4.jar driver from my project, I would expect it should not get it wrong? Do you have any idea what could be a reason here? Also - do you know if there is actually anything wrong with this query, because it does execute without error, except it just returns an empty list.

Comment: @jahrl Aaaahhhh ... So that is this! But do you have an idea why would it be? The same code on Java side (details irrelevant here) uses ojdbc driver with MySQL and it must be generating correct sql syntax because I never get an empty list, why would it fail with sqljdbc4.jar driver and SQL Server? This is actually auto generated code.

Comment: The driver does not "auto generate" any statements. The driver only executes statements that the Java program passes to it. Plus if with "ojdbc driver" you mean `ojdbc6.jar` then that is for **Oracle**, not for MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, my second comment was made in a hurry, t2 is a inner join table, so you can keep it's conditions in the WHERE clause. (But my first comment is still valid.)

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name It was a shortcut I used here - in fact I am using EclipseLink as JPA provide3r but the driver I believe actually does generate sql from JPQL? It is JPQL that is passed to driver, and the driver sqljdbc4.jar translates it to correct sql syntax - is it incorrect?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name Sorry my bad! It's a different driver for MySQL, nevertheless - it works in that other setup.

Comment: @jahrl Ok, thank you! But if that is the case do you know what is syntactically incorrect with this sql?? There must be something, since I get empty list only?

Comment: Starting with the idea that it was automatically generated, is there a way (using the query) of tracing a row which fits all the join conditions and where parameters to confirm it should generate something?

Comment: The syntax is perfectly fine! (I checked it with the SQL Validator, http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x)

Comment: @russ Probably, but to be honest I am NOT too familiar with SQL Server Management Studio. Do you actually know if there is any tool I could use to literally walk through this sql code?

Comment: No. The _driver_ **never** generates SQL (except for meta data API calls like `getTables()`). It's your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") that generates that SQL.

Comment: On the tool bar of the Management Studio there is a Parser icon and an Estimated Execution Plan icon, you can also use the SQL Server Profiler to further test the code.

Comment: If any one of the WHERE clause parameters isn't met it won't produce a sausage.

Comment: @russ funny part is - which one isn't? I look at this since yesterday and all are matched. I am only little bit worried that perhaps empty TransitiPunti table is a problem in SQL Server but if so how can I resolve it? In MySQL empty TransitiPunti table doesn't cause any issues here ...

Comment: I notice that in the WHERE clause the t2.IdTransiti must equal the t1.Id so despite the implicit join for the t2 table I would say this might be the issue. In MySQL do you get nulls for the t2 columns in the select?

Comment: The best resolution might be to delete the t2 join and the t2 where clause and the t2 columns in the select. If the table is empty you are not going to see anything from these anyway!

Comment: @russ Yes in MySQL I do get null values for the corresponding nulls and for those 4 columns but the query returns useful result unlike in SQL Server where it only returns empty list so far. Except in my case - this query is actually auto-generated by EclipseLink JPA provider via sqljdbc dirver and until I extract data from there I cannot know whether table is empty. I am working with legacy system and there are entities created which relies on those records, so it is not so simple. Yes if I drop inner joins it will work, but this is the point actually. I need to make it to work with them.

Comment: See my answer below without TransitiPunti.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The bracketing seems unusual, you might try replacing the current WHERE clause with this:

```
WHERE t6.Attiva = 1 
AND (t1.Istante BETWEEN '2015-09-03 00:16:50.693' AND '2015-09-03 23:16:50.693')
AND (t1.Partizione = 0 OR t1.Partizione = 6)
AND t1.IdCorsia = 1
AND t2.IdTransiti = t1.Id
AND t6.Id = t1.IdCorsia
ORDER BY t1.Istante DESC
```

If the transitipunti table is empty, try this:

```
SELECT t1.Id,
     t1.CodiceCaricoPericoloso,
     t1.Confidenza,
     t1.Istante,
     t1.IstanteRicezione,
     t1.Partizione,
     t1.Targa,
     t1.TargaSecondaria,
     t1.UtmcInstanceId,
     t1.VelocitaStimata,
     t1.IdColore,
     t1.IdCorsia,
     t1.IdMarca,
     t1.IdModello,
     t1.IdNazionalita,
     t1.IdSerie,
     t1.IdTipologiaVeicolo
FROM dbo.TransitiView t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Serie t0
   ON (t0.Id = t1.IdSerie)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Colori t3
   ON (t3.Id = t1.IdColore)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Modelli t4
   ON (t4.Id = t1.IdModello)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Marche t5
   ON (t5.Id = t1.IdMarca),
Corsie t6
WHERE t6.Attiva = 1 
AND (t1.Istante BETWEEN '2015-09-03 00:16:50.693' AND '2015-09-03 23:16:50.693')
AND (t1.Partizione = 0 OR t1.Partizione = 6)
AND t1.IdCorsia = 1
AND t6.Id = t1.IdCorsia
ORDER BY t1.Istante DESC
```

Null friendly Left Join in SQL Server:

```
create table abc
(
a int,
b int,
c int
)

create table def
(
d int,
e int,
f int
)

insert into abc values (1,2,3)

select * from abc left join def on abc.a = def.d or def.d = null
```

Comment: Thanks russ, but no difference.

Comment: Thank you! Perhabs I should edit my question actually - It does work without inner joins, I knew it actually before BUT THANKS TO YOU, I actually have realized why. It is because SQL Server seem odd and does not tolerate empty entries! Do you know if there is any way I can make SQL Server "LIKE" inner joins where the table is empty? It seem odd tha MySQL Server can handle these situations while SQL Server cannot. Has this happened to you before? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I always treat inner joins as necessarily requiring some data to give any result set. I would start (and I am not saying I've tried it) by thinking along the lines of putting 'or <tablealias.column> isnull' in the ON parameter...?

Comment: I thought to make it: ...ON (t2.IdTransiti = t1.Id or t2.IdTransiti is null) but that is not good enough for SQL Server. it didn't help :(.

Comment: Can do Left Join see my answer above! Of course Left join would but the code doesn't complain...haha (no me really). Well, why not Left Joins for the Corsie and the TransitiPunti?

Comment: Of course! That is so simple !!! And actually obvious, if you think about it! It ought to be left join not inner join! Thanks for this! I would up vote your answer, if I only had enough prestige. How come I didn't see it. Problem was wrong type of join! Embarrassing.

Comment: Well not necessarily too embarrassing Pawel, a lot of this as I am sure you are aware is about how we think about it. For me a Left Join is to get all the values from the Left column but by virtue of the fact it does that it would, of course, always produce rows even if the entire column of the right table were null, it would not usually be a regular approach to think of joining an empty column but certainly it's ok whether it has value or not. So QED!

Comment: I'm not sure what your "null friendly left join in SQL Server" is meant to demonstrate since it produces exactly the same result with and without the final `or def.d = null`.

Comment: But still I didn't have to add to JPQL string a test for nulls in MySQL. Perhaps it was auto-generated for me but in that case, it is still strange that whoever implemented JPQL translation to 'SQL Server tongue' haven't done it. And as pointed by @russ - there is no complain in a code, no exception, nothing at all! That is plainly WRONG.

Comment: I wonder whether at one time the implicit join would produce with nulls in the joined table. It is noticeable that the original code included an implicit join for the T2 table? If it used to do it it clearly doesn't do it now.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yep, you are right. No comment .... But still the original sql query as generated by the framework - DID NOT WORK and it doesn't although I cannot see anything wrong with the syntax. Can you?

Comment: @russ original query as it was generated by EclipseLink + sqljdbc.jar driver was as I presented, nothing more and nothing less - it did not work and it still doesn't. So something is still clearly wrong with those implicit joins and nulls.

Comment: yes, there are joins that are completely useless and not required and it mixes join styles between explicit and implied (which should never be done). The left joins in the original query are not the issue as they are entirely redundant. The only method for solving this is to "start small" and progressively introduce the joins and filtering conditions to see where it goes wrong. As we don't have the tables to work with you must do this as we cannot.

Comment: @Pawel can you just try adding AND (t2.IdTransiti = t1.Id or t2idTRansiti = null)) in the where part on the original code

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1bae0/1 (MySQL) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c32fb/1 (MSSQL) there is no difference in behaviour of a left join when the left table has no records in MySQL or MSSQL - this is basic and expected SQL behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If you think the table [TransitiPunti] has no records in it then yes that would stop any query using an INNER JOIN on that query from producing rows. note: Your existing query does use an **INNER JOIN** on that table (it uses old fashioned syntax regretably, but it is an inner join).

I suggest you test "progressively" so that you can work out the problem. "Start small", try that, if successful add items one at a time and try again.

As soon as you stop getting results you know what the last item was that you added, and it will be that item that causes the problem.

Here for example are 3 queries to try.

/* one table only (t1) */

```
SELECT
      t1.Id
    , t1.CodiceCaricoPericoloso
    , t1.Confidenza
    , t1.Istante
    , t1.IstanteRicezione
    , t1.Partizione
    , t1.Targa
    , t1.TargaSecondaria
    , t1.UtmcInstanceId
    , t1.VelocitaStimata
    , t1.IdColore
    , t1.IdCorsia
    , t1.IdMarca
    , t1.IdModello
    , t1.IdNazionalita
    , t1.IdSerie
    , t1.IdTipologiaVeicolo
FROM dbo.TransitiView t1
WHERE t1.Istante BETWEEN '2015-09-03 00:16:50.693' AND '2015-09-03 23:16:50.693'
      AND (t1.Partizione = 0 OR t1.Partizione = 6)
      AND t1.IdCorsia = 1
ORDER BY t1.Istante DESC
;
```

/* two tables (t1 & t6) */

```
SELECT
      t1.Id
    , t1.CodiceCaricoPericoloso
    , t1.Confidenza
    , t1.Istante
    , t1.IstanteRicezione
    , t1.Partizione
    , t1.Targa
    , t1.TargaSecondaria
    , t1.UtmcInstanceId
    , t1.VelocitaStimata
    , t1.IdColore
    , t1.IdCorsia
    , t1.IdMarca
    , t1.IdModello
    , t1.IdNazionalita
    , t1.IdSerie
    , t1.IdTipologiaVeicolo
FROM dbo.TransitiView t1
      INNER JOIN Corsie t6 ON t6.Id = t1.IdCorsia
WHERE t6.Attiva = 1
      AND t1.Istante BETWEEN '2015-09-03 00:16:50.693' AND '2015-09-03 23:16:50.693'
      AND (t1.Partizione = 0 OR t1.Partizione = 6)
      AND t1.IdCorsia = 1
ORDER BY t1.Istante DESC
;
```

/* three tables t1, t2, t6 */

```
SELECT
      t1.Id
    , t2.IdTransiti
    , t1.CodiceCaricoPericoloso
    , t1.Confidenza
    , t1.Istante
    , t1.IstanteRicezione
    , t2.SQLServer_latitude
    , t2.SQLServer_longitude
    , t1.Partizione
    , t1.Targa
    , t1.TargaSecondaria
    , t1.UtmcInstanceId
    , t1.VelocitaStimata
    , t1.IdColore
    , t1.IdCorsia
    , t1.IdMarca
    , t1.IdModello
    , t1.IdNazionalita
    , t1.IdSerie
    , t1.IdTipologiaVeicolo
FROM dbo.TransitiView t1
      INNER JOIN TransitiPunti t2 ON t2.IdTransiti = t1.Id
      INNER JOIN Corsie t6 ON t6.Id = t1.IdCorsia
WHERE t6.Attiva = 1
      AND t1.Istante BETWEEN '2015-09-03 00:16:50.693' AND '2015-09-03 23:16:50.693'
      AND (t1.Partizione = 0 OR t1.Partizione = 6)
      AND t1.IdCorsia = 1
ORDER BY t1.Istante DESC
```

NEVER EVER use a mixture of old join syntax with the (better) explicit ANSI joins.

I also dislike redundant parentheses, I believe they confuse rather than aid.

```
SELECT
      t1.Id
    , t2.IdTransiti
    , t1.CodiceCaricoPericoloso
    , t1.Confidenza
    , t1.Istante
    , t1.IstanteRicezione
    , t2.SQLServer_latitude
    , t2.SQLServer_longitude
    , t1.Partizione
    , t1.Targa
    , t1.TargaSecondaria
    , t1.UtmcInstanceId
    , t1.VelocitaStimata
    , t1.IdColore
    , t1.IdCorsia
    , t1.IdMarca
    , t1.IdModello
    , t1.IdNazionalita
    , t1.IdSerie
    , t1.IdTipologiaVeicolo
FROM dbo.TransitiView t1
      /*
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Serie t0 ON t0.Id = t1.IdSerie
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Colori t3 ON t3.Id = t1.IdColore
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Modelli t4 ON t4.Id = t1.IdModello
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Marche t5 ON t5.Id = t1.IdMarca
      */
      INNER JOIN TransitiPunti t2 ON t2.IdTransiti = t1.Id
      INNER JOIN Corsie t6 ON t6.Id = t1.IdCorsia
WHERE t6.Attiva = 1
      AND t1.Istante BETWEEN '2015-09-03 00:16:50.693' AND '2015-09-03 23:16:50.693'
      AND (t1.Partizione = 0 OR t1.Partizione = 6)
      AND t1.IdCorsia = 1
ORDER BY t1.Istante DESC
```

In taking out the parentheses and correcting for the join syntax I think the query looks like the above. Note there is no apparent need for any of the left joined tables.

by the way this:

```
AND (t1.Partizione = 0 OR t1.Partizione = 6)
```

could be changed to:

```
AND t1.Partizione IN (0,6)
```

Comment: Thanks, done that - believe me or not but your query still returns an empty list....

Comment: Yep there is data in a table. It's aactually a View not a table, but it should not matter, correct? For instance query select * from dbo.TransitiView where dbo.TransitiView.Partizione = 0 AND ... works correctly and returns data.

Comment: oh I believe you, but only you have the power to solve this. Try the reduced query first (just one table). That must supply data. If it does not then remove where clause conditions until it does. Then you will know why it returns no data.

Comment: Yes reduced query returns data from the table. My query was auto-generated from JPQL by jdbc driver. The problem though is why does the extended query does not ... :-) I will need an extended one actually. Here is a problem. It may be of importance: TransitiPunti is empty Corsie table has relevant data as it should and this worked fine with MySQL ?

Comment: You have a reduced query that produces a result. Great. Now add one more item. Did that work? (yes, ok, add one further item) (no, great, now we know what stops the results). ONLY you can do this, and ONLY you can see what query you executed and ONLY you can see the result. It is the process that is important. Start from the small query that works, then keep adding items until it stops working. Then you have your answer.